# Python Observing `str` calls by through sys.setprofile and frame inspection

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to python frame introspection and I am trying to set a profiler or a tracer in order to keep track of `str` function calls.  I have setup tracers in various ways but think I am missing some key understandings around frame introspection and how to get builtin function names (ie `str`)

```
def test_trace():
    sys.setprofile(trace_calls)
    hi = str('hellllo')
    stuff = []
    for i in range(10):
        stuff.append(str(random.randrange(0, 10000000000)))
    print(hi)
    os._exit(0)

def trace_calls(frame, event, arg):
    '''
    if event not in ('call', 'c_call'):
        return
    '''
    stack = collections.deque()
    stack.appendleft(_expand_arg(arg) + _expand_frame(frame))

    while frame.f_back is not None:
        stack.appendleft(_expand_arg(arg) + _expand_frame(frame))
        frame = frame.f_back

    print('-' * 100)
    for frame in stack:
        print(frame)

def _expand_arg(arg):
    if arg is None:
        return ()

    return (
        # arg.__name__,
    )

def _expand_frame(frame):
    code = frame.f_code
    c_class = ''
    c_module = ''
    if 'self' in frame.f_locals:
        c_class = frame.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__
        c_module = frame.f_locals['self'].__class__.__module__

    return (
        code.co_filename,
        frame.f_lineno,
        frame.f_trace,
        code.co_name,
        code.co_firstlineno,
        c_class,
        c_module,
    )
```

When I run `test_trace()` I see no mention of any `str` calls in any of the profiled events.  I would expect to see some mention of `str` or `<string>` in some of the call stacks but only see the random calls:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py', 125, None, 'start_ipython', 99, '', '')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py', 658, None, 'launch_instance', 650, '', '')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py', 356, None, 'start', 350, 'TerminalIPythonApp', 'IPython.terminal.ipapp')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py', 485, None, 'mainloop', 478, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.in
teractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py', 476, None, 'interact', 458, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.in
teractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2662, None, 'run_cell', 2636, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.inte
ractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2785, None, '_run_cell', 2669, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.int
eractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2909, None, 'run_ast_nodes', 2835, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal
.interactiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2963, None, 'run_code', 2933, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.inte
ractiveshell')
('<ipython-input-2-a29a88804d82>', 1, None, '<module>', 1, '', '')
('/vagrant_data/github.com/dm03514/python-apm/pythonapm/instruments/monkey.py', 35, None, 'test_trace', 30, '', '')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/random.py', 194, None, 'randrange', 170, 'Random', 'random')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/random.py', 232, None, '_randbelow', 220, 'Random', 'random')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/random.py', 232, None, '_randbelow', 220, 'Random', 'random')

('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py', 125, None, 'start_ipython', 99, '', '')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py', 658, None, 'launch_instance', 650, '', '')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py', 356, None, 'start', 350, 'TerminalIPythonApp', 'IPython.terminal.ipapp')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py', 485, None, 'mainloop', 478, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.in
teractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py', 476, None, 'interact', 458, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.in
teractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2662, None, 'run_cell', 2636, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.inte
ractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2785, None, '_run_cell', 2669, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.int
eractiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2909, None, 'run_ast_nodes', 2835, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal
.interactiveshell')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py', 2963, None, 'run_code', 2933, 'TerminalInteractiveShell', 'IPython.terminal.inte
ractiveshell')
('<ipython-input-2-a29a88804d82>', 1, None, '<module>', 1, '', '')
('/vagrant_data/github.com/dm03514/python-apm/pythonapm/instruments/monkey.py', 35, None, 'test_trace', 30, '', '')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/random.py', 194, None, 'randrange', 170, 'Random', 'random')
('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/random.py', 194, None, 'randrange', 170, 'Random', 'random')
```

---

I've seen string calls in the python builtin profiles [so I tried to look at how they get the c function names](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/profile.py#L187), in case that `str` was delegating to a c call.

I tried to get the c function calls by inspecting `arg` (both with `setprofile` and `settrace` but it didn't show any string calls either

```
    if event == "c_call":
        self.c_func_name = arg.__name__
```

Is anyone familiar with how to trace the python `str` or built in calls.

Comment: Did you see [this post](https://bugs.python.org/issue17799)? It doesn't look encouraging. _The reason not to pass C calls to the tracing function is that tracing exists to support pdb and other debuggers, and pdb only cares about tracing through Python code. So the docs should be updated._ (Guido van Rossum, Jan 2018)

Comment: Even if you could trace your calls to `str`, it wouldn’t cover things like `"%s"%x`, `"".join(…)`, _etc_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run test_trace() I see no mention of any str calls in any of the profiled events.

That's because `str()` is a *type object* defined entirely in C. Only *function calls* are traced, not type calls, so no `c_call` event is issued.

You could work around this by replacing the `str` built-in; you can alter Python's builtins via the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

```
import builtins

orig_str = builtins.str
def traceable_str(*args):
    return orig_str(*args)
builtins.str = traceable_str
```

You can now see `traceable_str` calls be passed to the profiling function.

However, note that only *calls from Python code to `str()`* will be traced! Anything implemented in C, like the `print()` function, doesn't even call the `str()` builtin, it just uses the C API to achieve the same results.